# Recursivelly cd to a parent directory

Tags: zsh

I am often working with Wordpress, editing a stylesheet in my editor where my 'Open in Terminal' command will launch my shell in a location such as (for example):

```
/home/user/work/project/wp/wp-content/themes/theme_name/_/inc/scss
```

I was wondering if there is any way I could easily go to this folder:

```
/home/user/work/project
```

without having to type out `cd ../../../../../../../` and if there was some sort of way to wildcard the number of parent directories until it reaches the folder named `project`? (I know I could simply `cd ~/work/project` but am wondering if I can go to other particular parent folders from the current child)

In a psueudocode description, I was wondering if there's any way to `keep going back to the parent until reaching the first folder named ______`

The same question could apply going deeper as well where a `cd **/desired_folder` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> produces a list of child folders/files I am looking for, is there a way to do this in the other direction as well?

Answer (score 5):

I have this in my `.zshrc` (thanks [Adaephon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2992551/adaephon) for the tip):

```
# cd to a parent directory
function pcd { cd ${PWD%/$1/*}/$1; }
```

### Usage example

```
$ pwd
~
$ mkdir -p a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k
$ cd **/k
$ pwd
~/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k
$ pcd d
$ pwd
~/a/b/c/d
```

Comment: If there is more than one directory with the same name as the target directory in the current path (e.g. `~/a/b/c/a/b/c`), this will always go to the topmost one. If you want to go to the first matching directory when going up, you could use `function { cd ${PWD%/$1/*}/$1 }`.

Comment: @Adaephon: Thanks for the tip, I'm normally not it that case so mine was working fine until now, but your solution seems more sound.